# docker-compose up command throwing error when deploying a parse server

Tags: docker, npm, docker-compose, parse-server

I am trying to run my parse server app in docker, but when running the command 'docker-compose up' it runs fine for some seconds and then throws this error:
**Error parsing command line: unrecognised option '--break-mongo'**.
and after this it also throws an npm related error --

> my-parse-app |
> my-parse-app | > app@1.0.0 start /parse-server
> my-parse-app | > parse-server "/parse-server/config/config.json"
> my-parse-app |
> my-parse-app |
> /parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/ParseObject.js:1301
> my-parse-app |   async exists(options
> my-parse-app |         ^^^^^^
> my-parse-app |
> my-parse-app | SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
> my-parse-app |     at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
> my-parse-app |     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
> my-parse-app |     at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
> my-parse-app |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
> my-parse-app |     at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
> my-parse-app |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
> my-parse-app |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
> my-parse-app |     at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
> my-parse-app |     at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
> my-parse-app |     at Object.
> (/parse-server/node_modules/parse/lib/node/ParseRole.js:12:43)
> my-parse-app |
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! Linux 4.19.128-microsoft-standard
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node"
> "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start" "--" "/parse-server/config/config.json"
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! node v6.17.1
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! app@1.0.0 start: `parse-server "/parse-server/config/config.json"`
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! Exit status 1
> my-parse-app | npm ERR!
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! Failed at the app@1.0.0 start script
> 'parse-server "/parse-server/config/config.json"'.
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of
> node.js and npm installed.
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with
> the app package,
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! not with npm itself.
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your
> system:
> my-parse-app | npm ERR!     parse-server
> "/parse-server/config/config.json"
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an
> issue for this project with:
> my-parse-app | npm ERR!     npm bugs app
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their
> info via:
> my-parse-app | npm ERR!     npm owner ls app
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output
> above.
> my-parse-app |
> my-parse-app | npm ERR! Please include the following file with any
> support request:
> my-parse-app | npm ERR!     /parse-server/npm-debug.log
> my-parse-app exited with code 1

My docker-compose:

```
version: "2"
services:
# Node.js parse-server application image
  app:
    build: ./app
    command: npm start -- /parse-server/config/config.json
    container_name: my-parse-app
    volumes:
    - ./app:/parse-server/
    - /parse-server/node_modules
    ports:
    - "1337:1337"
    links:
    - mongo
# MongoDB image 

  mongo:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: mongo-database
    ports:
    - "27017:27017"
    volumes_from:
    - mongodata
# MongoDB image volume for persistence
  mongodata:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
    - ./data/db:/data/db
    command:
    - --break-mongo
```

My Dockerfile

```
FROM node:boron
RUN mkdir -p /parse-server
WORKDIR /parse-server
COPY . /parse-server
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

[The break-mongo error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4nV2.jpg)

[The npm error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7Hy4.png)

Comment: As @DaviMacêdo mentioned, this is a NodeJS version issue. From your `docker-compose` file, the change will need to happen in the `Dockerfile` in your "`./app`" folder.

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are using an old version of node and it is probably the problem. Switch the first line of your docker file to:

```
FROM node:erbium
```